# Google Script COPY and PASTE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to copy and paste multiple cell values to another cell on my sheet. Basically, if I edit cell "AM13", it should copy it's old value to "C23". This part is working, but the other cell, which is "N12" is not copy and pasting on cell "C25".

Here's my code right now:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'AM13') {
var wspaste = e.source.getRange('Sheet1!C24');
var wspaste2 = e.source.getA1Notation().getRange('Sheet1!N12');
var wspaste3  = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('Sheet1!N12').getValue();
var OLDVALUE;
OLDVALUE = e.oldValue;
wspaste.setValue(OLDVALUE);
wspaste2.setValue(wspaste3);
}
}
```

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14DK6SmKuNVBaA3wn3wfea3ePc5Hii_5h94ykwcZ7-n0/edit?usp=sharing) a copy of my sheet!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're using merged cells. This makes it difficult to to tell where and from where you want to get and to put values.

*Probably* you need something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'AM13') {

    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('Sheet1!C24').setValue(e.oldValue);

    var value = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('Sheet1!N13').getValue();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('Sheet1!C25').setValue(value);

  }
}
```

To debug `onEdit()` function I'm used to use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(value)` where `value` is any value you want to check. It works almost like `console.log()` or `Logger.log()`

For example to show the content of `e.range.getA1Notation()`:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(e.range.getA1Notation())
```

It will show you at the bottom-right corner the window with the value:

[image]